# Operation not applicable Delphi Clientdataset

Tags: mysql, delphi-xe3, tclientdataset

Por que estou recebendo o erro `Operation not applicable` quando eu abro um `TClientDataset` com dados *mestre-detalhe*, porem é apenas um `dataset` e um *detalhe*.

Modo de sistema : DataSnap > no Servidor qryPai/dspPai/dsPai.

datasetPai `SQL "select * from orcamento_atendimento where orcamento_atendimento_id = :orcamento_atendimento_id"`

```
qryFilho/dspFilho (ligação como pai pelo "mastersource = dsPai / masterfilds =
orcamento_atendimento_id")
```

**datasetFilho**

```sql
SQL "select o.orcamento_id,
       o.sequencial,
       o.orcamento_status_id,
       s.descricao,
       s.faturar,
       o.orcamento_atendimento_id,
       o.vendedor_id,
       v.nome as vendedor,
       o.data_orcamento,
       o.data_validade,
       o.observacoes

from orcamento o
    left join orcamento_status s
      on s.orcamento_status_id = o.orcamento_status_id
    left join pessoa v
      on v.pessoa_id = o.vendedor_id
where o.orcamento_atendimento_id = :orcamento_atendimento_id"
```

No cliente:

```
ClienteDataSet_Pai / remoteserver = dspOrcamento / providername = dspPai

clienteDataset_Filho / datasetfield = datasource_paidatasetFilho
```

Quando faço as ligações tudo correto, mas quando eu tento abrir ou adicionar os campos o erro ocorre.

Comment: O dataset detalhe está adicionado como campo ao dataset pai?